# “Compilation Error CS1513: } expected” in temp file, triggered by empty line 1 in cshtml file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

So yeah, I got an “Object expected” error, only it isn’t in any of the files I touch, it is in a temp file!!

```
Source File: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\6005bb52\5da39716\App_Web_delete.cshtml.d3c9d87b.bz6umh4r.0.cs    Line: 455
```

And no, there are only two `{` characters in the cshtml file that triggers this, and all of them have end braces. As in, within VS 2015 it is the Delete.cshtml file that has the red squigglies under the file name, and the Error window claims the missing `}` is supposed to be on line 1 of that cshtml file. Problem is, the only thing on line one is the `@model` declaration, and that has no curly brackets!

Do I have to rescaffold the entire model? Because that would suck. Have already tried cleaning and rebuilding both project and solution.

Delete.cshtml:

```
@model CCS.Models.EventCode

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Delete the Event “" + @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventCodeName) + "”.";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
  <hr />
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventType.EventTypeName)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EventType.EventTypeName)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventCodeName)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EventCodeName)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventCodeDescription)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EventCodeDescription)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventCodeDate)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EventCodeDate)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Active)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Recorded)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Recorded)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Modified)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Modified)</dd>
    <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TouchedBy)</dt><dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TouchedBy)</dd>
  </dl>

  @using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">[
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
      @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</div> ]
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Show your Delete.cshtml file if you think it's related.

Comment: [mason](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1139830/mason): done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhh… could plain text content trigger this error? Because I just made a change in the layout of plain-text content, and the issue vanished.

See the final `div`, the one that holds the submit and back actions? Since there is a pipe `|` between them, I prefer to visually enclose the entire group with square brackets `[]`. Sort of my personal æsthetic quirk that any list separated by pipes needs to be enclosed by square brackets. Well, I just noticed that I put the closing square bracket outside of the closing `</div>`. So I moved it seven spaces to the left… and the issue vanished.

All I can say is ಠ_ಠ Whiskey-Tango-Foxtrot. How does a purely text-based square closing bracket outside of a closing div affect the system like this?

Purely for sh*ts and giggles, I put the closing `</div>` on its own line, and moved the square bracket both inside and outside of the div. Inside: no error. Outside: error. So what if I actually wanted a square bracket sitting outside of that div?? Would I have had to call up the HTML character entity for a closing square bracket just to prevent this issue?

IMHO without a reasonable and rational explanation this is just f**ked six ways to Sunday. I mean, `]` ≠ `\}` in most any universe I know of.